# Seeking a very low cost buck boost 3 V or 5 V to 3.3 V

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, arm, buck-boost

I am seeking an SMPS chip for ARM/LoRa PS circuit which needs to use every drop of energy at 3.3 V from a pair of LR6-AA batteries (3V) or use 5V USB.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use [TPS63900](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS63900). Below circuit is created using TI webench.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  Has excellent and superior quiescent current as well.